# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt - KeyError: 'keymap.quit_all'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When I enter the code above, I get the following error

```
#( conda install matplotlib/ python 3.5.2/ anaconda 3.4.2 / window10)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Users\kimjimin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     36 from matplotlib.cbook import deprecated, warn_deprecated
     37 from matplotlib import docstring
---> 38 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
     39 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
     40 from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

C:\Users\kimjimin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in <module>()
     51 import numpy as np
     52 
---> 53 from matplotlib import (
     54     backend_tools as tools, cbook, colors, textpath, tight_bbox, transforms,
     55     widgets, get_backend, is_interactive, rcParams)

C:\Users\kimjimin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_tools.py in <module>()
    389 
    390 
--> 391 class ToolQuitAll(ToolBase):
    392     """Tool to call the figure manager destroy method"""
    393 

C:\Users\kimjimin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_tools.py in ToolQuitAll()
    393 
    394     description = 'Quit all figures'
--> 395     default_keymap = rcParams['keymap.quit_all']
    396 
    397     def trigger(self, sender, event, data=None):

C:\Users\kimjimin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    904                 val = alt_val(val)
    905             elif key in _deprecated_set and val is not None:
--> 906                 if key.startswith('backend'):
    907                     warnings.warn(self.msg_backend_obsolete.format(key),
    908                                   mplDeprecation)

KeyError: 'keymap.quit_all'
```